# "future cannot be sent between threads safely" error

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have the following code I have some compilation problems with.

```
pub trait ATrait {
    async fn afunc(&self, x: u32) -> u32;
}
struct ATraitWrapper<T: ATrait + Send + Clone + 'static> {
    inner: T,
}
impl<T: ATrait + Send + Clone + 'static> ATrait for ATraitWrapper<T> {
    async fn afunc(&self, x: u32) -> u32 {
        let (tx, rx) = std::sync::mpsc::channel();
        let inner_clone = self.inner.clone();
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            let result = inner_clone.afunc(x).await;
            tx.send(result).expect("Failed to send through channel")
        });
        rx.recv().expect("Failed to receive from channel")
    }
}

pub struct MyStruct {
    value: u32,
}

impl ATrait for MyStruct {
    async fn afunc(&self, x: u32) -> u32 {
        self.value + x
    }
}
```

The error I get is on `tokio::spawn`:

```
error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src/lib.rs:11:9
    |
11  |         tokio::spawn(async move {
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^ future created by async block is not `Send`
    |
    = help: within `{async block@src/lib.rs:11:22: 14:10}`, the trait `Send` is not implemented for `impl Future<Output = u32>`
note: future is not `Send` as it awaits another future which is not `Send`
   --> src/lib.rs:12:26
    |
12  |             let result = inner_clone.afunc(x).await;
    |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ await occurs here on type `impl Future<Output = u32>`, which is not `Send`
note: required by a bound in `tokio::spawn`
   --> /playground/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/tokio-1.36.0/src/task/spawn.rs:166:21
    |
164 |     pub fn spawn<F>(future: F) -> JoinHandle<F::Output>
    |            ----- required by a bound in this function
165 |     where
166 |         F: Future + Send + 'static,
    |                     ^^^^ required by this bound in `spawn`
help: `Send` can be made part of the associated future's guarantees for all implementations of `ATrait::afunc`
    |
2   -     async fn afunc(&self, x: u32) -> u32;
2   +     fn afunc(&self, x: u32) -> impl std::future::Future<Output = u32> + Send;
    |
```

The type of the closure is `Future<Output=()>`, why can't it be `Send`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that one *can* write valid implementations of `ATrait` that do not produce a `Send` future from `afunc` for example:

```rust
impl ATrait for () {
    async fn afunc(&self, x: u32) -> u32{
        // holding `y` a `!Send` `Rc` makes the `Future` returned
        // by this function `!Send`
        let y = std::rc::Rc::new(());
        std::future::ready(()).await;
        *y;
        x
    }
}
```

and your code being generic has to work for **every** possible implementation (even nonsensical ones like my example).

The compiler aready suggests a fix for this, that disallows such definitions use

```rust
    fn afunc(&self, x: u32) -> impl Future<Output = u32> + Send;
```

as your method signature instead.

Comment: But the type of the closure is `Future<Output=()>`, not `Future<Output = u32>`

Comment: The problem is `afunc` and you `await`ing it in the closure. Awaiting a non-`Send` `Future` makes your `Future` `!Send` as well. The `Output` of the `Future` is of no consequence whatsoever for it being `Send` or `Sync`.